# SUMIFS (not blank, and othe conditions)

Tags: excel, sumifs, is-empty

I am trying to use [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) to sum a couple of conditions. I want my sum range to be ***column A*** and my first criteria range is ***column B***, the criteria is that ***column B*** has something in it or essentially it isn't blank/0. The next criteria is if ***column C*** matches the year which is simple and I can get that to work, but my problem arises from the criteria of the first test. I have tried:

1. `SUMIFS(column A, column B, column B > 0, column C, "16")`
2. `SUMIFS(column A, column B, column B <> 0, column C, "16")`
3. `SUM(SUMIFS(column A, column B, "1", column C, "16"), SUMIFS(column A, column B, "2", column C, "16"), SUMIFS(column A, column B, "3", column C, "16")`...

Obviously, I do not want to use option 3 but it did seem to give me the right result. If I knew that the number in column B would be always under 5 then I may use this but as of now, I have to assume the number in column B can be from 0-1000. Is there something I am missing here? 
 All I want to do is sum up ***column A*** if ***column B*** is not blank or 0. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `SUMIFS()` with comparison as criteria by enclosing your criteria in quotation marks:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,">0")
```

Note that `>0` criteria also works for blank cells as Excel evaluates them to zero.

However, if you do it this way:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"<>0")
```

blank cells will pass the criteria, only cells containing `0` value will be skipped.

Comment: Wow... So I just need to surround my criteria with quotation marks? For the first attempt would the correct syntax be: "column B > 0" or column B ">0"? BTW when I say column A/B/C I mean the reference so it would be 'sheet 1'!$A:$A but I imagine you understood that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The correct syntax in your notation would be `=SUMIFS('sheet 1'!$A:$A,'sheet 1'!$B:$B,">0",...,...)`

Comment: ^ Thanks, I should have commented after I tried it on excel :P. Helpful, correct response, thank you very much! If you wouldn't mind I also have another outstanding excel question that is a bit tricky -> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792044/if-stmt-false-eval-next-row)

Answer (score 7):

Better answer found at [ExcelJet](https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-if-not-blank)

Use only `"<>"` as criteria, e.g.

```
=SUMIF(C5:C11,"<>",D5:D11)
```

This allows rows in criteria column to be included if their value is zero, thus excluding ONLY blanks in the criteria column.

Answer (score -1):

I am not getting correct result with "<>".
Column A contains numbers. Column B has formulas which gives an amount or a blank.
I used the formula '=SUMIF(B:B,"<>",A:A)'.
This formula adds up all numbers in Column A, even if corresponding cells in Column B are blank (based on formula)

Comment: Welcome Bipin. Please **edit** your answer to correct the formula, rather than adding a comment.

Comment: Bipin, try "< >" with a space between the chevrons.  Typing "<>" without the space causes the error you are getting.